# Questionnaire eveluation

Tags: php, algorithm, symfony, design-patterns

My team is required to build a questionnaire evaluation process, and I am wondering how to approach it (data and algorithm wise).

The process is described as such:

1. Asking the user some "placement" questions - age, gender, grade, geographical location.
2. Determining the "reference group" the user belongs to (10 years old, 3rd grade, Female in California)
3. Grabbing the relevant parameters - GPA, after school activities, digital behavior markers (could be different based on reference group parameters)
4. Asking the user "parameter related" questions ("what is your math grade?", "How many android based devices do you own?")
5. Benchmarking the user in comparison to pre-existing parameter data (5th percentile of GPA, more devices than 70% of similar users, etc).

So, for example, I should know that:

- For a 10 years old, after school activities is a relevant parameter
- For a 10 years old in 3rd grade in California 70% of users have more than x devices

I do have the data, and able to structure it however I want. Our language of choice is PHP and framework of choice is Symfony2, but for a good enough reason I will reconsider :)

I would love getting **any** ideas on how to tackle this. Seriously, even a drawing would help :P

Answer (score 0):

Is this web based? If so you will need some html forms to display the question. Then you will need to process an POST request to extract the data. Next you will need to store the data, probably a database. When you have collected all the data you will then need to do your statistical analysis.

Statistically you will need to decide what you hypothesis is and use the relevant test to use. Hopefully you have been taught some, you might need a test which compares groups.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I require no assistance in terms of the basics of building a web application :) Instead, I am seeking advice on the general matching algorithm to use and data analysis process to follow.

Comment: Your probably best asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/ which will  be able to advise on the right statistical tests to use.

You do really need to start with a precisely stated hypothesis you wish to test. Thats where statistics start. 

If you just want to explore the data, plot a few graphs to see what might be a good hypothesis then try a package like R or a spreadsheet.